# Null-coalescing out parameter doesnt give error

Tags: c#, out, null-coalescing

This question describes a error related to using Null-coalescing, Null-conditional and out parameter:
[Null-coalescing out parameter gives unexpected warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207014/null-coalescing-out-parameter-gives-unexpected-warning?newreg=37b0cc9c78a8455180ce8eaffc09a2cb)
The answer details the reasons for this error.

But when I copy the example from the question to my project, I don't get an error and everything compiles. I encountered the fact that the project is compiled on my computer, but others have problems. Does it depend on the environment? What environment?

Project uses .net5 and С#8.0. I tried VS2022, Rider and console msbuild as compiler, all of them compile successfully.

Comment: Do you have nullable context on or off?

Comment: [If you're using .NET 5 you _won't_ be using C# 8.0 - .NET 5 is tied-to C# 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5). MSBuiild will bump your language version to match the current .NET version target - and IIRC it will just ignore any attempt to override it via your `.csproj`.

Comment: @Dai: MSBuild respects what you explicitly put in `LangVersion` yourself, regardless of your .NET version and whether or not it will work. You can use C# 11 with .NET 4.8 if you so please, and it will work as long as no features are used that require runtime and/or library support.

Comment: My .csproj file does not have <Nullable> element, so it is at default setting.

Comment: I tried to create new console solution and code from question still works for me, so lang version doesnt matter.

Comment: @JeroenMostert "whether or not it will work" is the operative phrase though: the entire build system (both MSBuild and `csc.exe` itself) conspire against using C# 8.0 or higher when targeting .NET Framework 4.x alone _unless_ you're using multi-targeting, for example - otherwise you get an unsupported lang-version+target error message and the build fails.

Comment: What .NET SDKs do you have installed? Have you tried "fix" one used for the project by using [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json)?

Comment: @Dai: I can't replicate it. Maybe if you're using old-style project files, or starting things from old MSBuild versions rather than the SDK? New-style project files (which are required to be able to do multi-targeting, but they can single-target just fine) allow any combination of `<TargetFramework>` and `<LangVersion>` (and I do mean any -- C# 1 and .NET 7 combine, if you insist, though few non-trivial programs could be compiled that way). If you're using .NET 5 as the OP is, you are *certainly* using `dotnet` and a new-style project file, so there's definitely no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a later version of the compiler installed (compared to your colleagues machines). From the [Select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version) doc:

> The SDK uses the latest installed version

And C# 10 has a [Improved Definite Assignment Analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/improved-definite-assignment) implemented which seems to fix the issue in the linked question (check out the examples).

Try adding [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file to the project root to set the used SDK to compile the project. Something like:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "5.0.0",
    "rollForward": "latestMinor"
  }
}
```

And then try compiling again (my current guess is that it should result in error, another thing to check - .NET SDKs installed on your colleagues machines - use `dotnet --list-sdks`, in theory this check could just have been backported to .NET 5 SDK).

Comment: It means I get "Improved Definite Assignment Analysis" from C# 10, but not other new features like "not" pattern? Which doesn't work for me.

Comment: @EugenePavlyuk basically yes. It will require a more deep knowledge of the compiler but analysis can be implemented as language-version agnostic while patterns require specific language version set. You actually can try setting a higher language version than a supported one by used .NET version and some of newer language stuff will work (if newer compiler is present).

Answer (score 1):

The analyzer has been improved in C#10 for similar expressions, you can check these links for details.

[[Proposal]: Improved Definite Assignment Analysis](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4465)

[Improved definite assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#improved-definite-assignment)

If you use an old compiler, the error is reproduciable. Here is an [example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgJgpgtg9gzgWgE4QMYyWOAfAAgJgEYBYAKFwAYACXQgFgG4yyCqBhMgbzKt5rqoAhABQBKHn26k+MqgDcAhkipgAlqgAuVALxUAdhADuVACLqNqmHqUBPADyq9GgDQ1CFAHxim02b0XKKHAArgA2WrrCapoA/AB0ACpINgDiEBoAagqhwRDChK4wwVoB8tm5olQxMVQAZtlwEJU1ijkQVCBUAEQmEPVhGl0+MgC+ZCNAA) on SharpLab.